# How do I check that number is divisible by two and three in LISP?

Tags: math, numbers, lisp

I need to check if given number is divisible by 2 (if yes, output should be 2), by 3( if yes, output should be 3) and if number is not divisible by 2 or 3 (eg 11) output should be same as given number.

Here is my code:

```
(defun funk (a)    
(cond 
  ((evenp a)2) 
 ((rem a 3)3)
 (t a) 
))
```

it shows 3 even if i define a as 11.

Comment: What should happen when the number is divisable with both`3` and `2`? How ti is now it prioritzes `2`.

Comment: Nice: You are obviously a C programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the remainder is zero.

```
((zerop (rem a 3)) 3)
```